# REGEX_dynamic substitution using function

Tags: python

```
def hide_reserve_3(s):
    return '*' * (len(s[0])-3) + s[0][-3:]

re.sub(r'\d+', hide_reserve_3, 'User\'s mobile number is 1234567890')
```

output: "User's mobile number is *******890"

Above I've retrieved from
https://medium.com/towards-data-science/7-useful-tricks-for-python-regex-you-should-know-ec20381e22f2

I just don't quite get why there is a slicing operation in the function. (s[0])
Can someone please explain it to me thoroughly what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: when a function is used as the _repl_ parameter of `re.sub()`, that function gets a `match` object as an argument when it's called. And `[0]` of a match is the entire matched string. If you had capture groups in the pattern those would be `[1]` etc..

Comment: `s[0]` is not slicing, its to get the string value from the `Match` (`s`) object.

Comment: try putting a `print(s)` statement in the middle of the function and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function with comments:

```py
def hide_reserve_3(s):
    return '*' * (len(s[0])-3) + s[0][-3:]
    #       ^ repeat * length        ^ slice for last 3 characters
    #         of string - 3
```

So this function builds an output consisting of a string with `*` repeated the length of the input `s` minus 3, concatenated with the final 3 digits in `s`.

The outer call to `re.sub` will match every number substring in the input and replace it by using the above slicing function.